Linux install using a SSD, 2 pcie nvme drives and a hdd drive - Boot/efi partition nightmares
I have a Fujitsu R930 Workstation which I want to use as a linux dev workstation...
I have 1 SATA-6 1tb SSD, 2 pcie nvme drives (1tb/2tb) and a SATA hdd drive (1tb).
The pcie nvme drives are not bootable as they are not recognised as bootable devices by the R930 bios.
I have been trying to install Linux so that I use the SSD for the efi, boot and var directories, the 1tb nvme for / - the 2tb nvme for /home and the hdd as a /timeshift directory...
I can define all this during the graphical install process but every time I try to boot into the fresh install I get a grub cli and cant boot the OS...
I have tried using Ubuntu 24.04, Debian 12.6, Linux Mint 21.3 and Redhat EL 9.4..
I set the efi partition as 512mb and have tried leaving it unformatted and formatted using fat32, creating a ext2/4 2gb boot portion (tried ext2/4 and not creating a boot partition at all and just having the efi partition) and the remaining partitions/disks are formatted using ext4...
I always get the same grub cli on first reboot...
So I end up just letting the install process use the full ssd and then once installed I move the /home and /var partitions to the nvmes and create the /timeshift mount...
This is a real pain to have to do and I would like to understand if/how I can just set this during the install process...
I really am at my wits end with this, as I having been trying all sorts of permutations with no joy,  so any help will be much appreciated...

Hi Mark, unless you have a specific reason you need the better performance of NVMe, I'd honestly probably just stick with a SATA SSD. I've been through the whole "bootstrapping using another storage medium" thing before (though admittedly, with ZFS instead), and while it's totally possible, it's never been worth the pain.

Thanks, you are right! - I for various reasons I have moved /home to a nvme and /var to an nvme - but i did it once the base OS was installed on a single SSD... it seems crazy though that this process isn't accounted for during the install process on any of the distro's I tried... having said that, I recently installed (and removed, lol) windows 11 pro and that wouldn't allow for a sdd to be used for just the boot partitions and then install the OS on an nvem... crazy... Thanks for the comment, and all the best!

It seems that this is not possible!
I switched back to Debian 12.6 and when you select 'use entire' disk' it does give you the option to put everything in / or to use separate partitions for home, var etc... but if you select this option, the installer only seems to allow you to create partitions for these on the same disk that / is being installed on...
This seems crazy as it would be really handy if at this stage you could select a secondary disk, but alas the installer doesn't seem to allow for this...
Debian and all the other distros I tried seem to allow you to lay out partitions across a number of disks and set boot flags and Boot-EFI lables, but for me the system would always boot straight to a grub menu...
So I think I will stick to installing the OS on one bootable disk and then migrate any partitions to secondary disks as needed...
Its not that hard to do just time consuming...
find the disk info of the target/new disk
lsblk

Then:
sudo mount /dev/<partition> /mnt/
cd /mnt
sudo rm -rf lost+found
sudo cp -rp /home/* /mnt
sudo mv /home /home-old
sudo mkdir /home
umount /dev/<disk>
sudo mount /dev/<partition> /home/
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.old
sudo nano /etc/fstab

add disk and /home entry something like the below
/dev/<partition>    /home     ext4    defaults    0     0    

reboot...
once happy /home is correct then:
sudo rm -fr /home-old

Its more of less the same process for /var etc...
Hope this is useful...
